# Remove reg ex data annotation with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I have a form submission that is handled with ajax.  As part of this submission I ask for a postcode, for which I use a regular expression, to make sure that the data entered is in the correct format.  However, I have recently discovered that address details may not be know at the time of submission so I need the postcode field to be able to accept a value of tbc but only when a (Not yet known) checkbox is checked.  By adding:

```
$("#FormDutyHolder_Postcode").rules("remove", "regex-pattern")
```

to my code:

```
    $('.checkBoxes').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

  $("#FormDutyHolder_Postcode").rules("remove", "regex-pattern")

   $("#FormDutyHolder_Postcode").val("Tbc");
   $("#FormDutyHolder_Postcode").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  }
    });
```

I am able to get past the client side validation & hit the controller, however the postcode value comes through as an empty string.

Ajax code (that works fine without the line to remove the reg ex pattern):

```
  $(document).on('click', '#Update', function () {

            var dutyholderRoleId;         

            //condition statement defines the role that is selected from the radio input.
            if (globalDutyholderRoleId > 3) {               

                dutyholderRoleId = $('#FormDutyHolder_RoleId:checked').val();

            } else {

                dutyholderRoleId = globalDutyholderRoleId;
            }

            var $form = $('#form0');
            if ($form.valid()) {

                $.ajax({

                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ProjectTeamAddDutyHolder',
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: {
                        formDutyHolderId: $('#FormDutyHolder_DutyHolderId').val(),
                        dutyholderName: $('#FormDutyHolder_DutyHolderName').val(),
                        dutyholderEmail: $('#FormDutyHolder_Email').val(),
                        dutyholderTelephone: $('#FormDutyHolder_Telephone').val(),
                        dutyholderAddress1: $('#FormDutyHolder_Address1').val(),
                        dutyholderAddress2: $('#FormDutyHolder_Address2').val(),
                        dutyholderAddress3: $('#FormDutyHolder_Address3').val(),
                        dutyholderTown: $('#FormDutyHolder_Town').val(),
                        dutyholderCounty: $('#FormDutyHolder_County').val(),
                        dutyholderPostcode: $('#FormDutyHolder_Postcode').val(),
                        dutyholderRoleId: dutyholderRoleId,
                        dutyholderCountryId: $('#FormDutyHolder_CountryId').val(),
                    }
                    ,
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#Update').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from the regex issue, remove `async: false`. It's very bad practice, and you don't need it anyway because you're using the `success` callback. Also, reloading the page after making an AJAX request renders it rather redundant.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I am using a modal for input so need to use the client side validation with ajax.  Once it gets past the client side validation, the page reload is fine because it will close the modal & update the displayed list, every time a new set of data is added